# Ratchet Modal closing not appeating

Tags: modal-dialog, ratchet-2

I created 2 modals  but  the bar is coming behind another bar  and the closing icon X not showing , what can i do ?

link http://www.techana.com/About/
"the icons are the modals "

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this about problems of modal header on iOS 8 https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/679

For problems about iOS header modal this fix (linked salesforce mobile SDK) worked:

```
header.bar.bar-nav {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    }
```